# SSRS - How to hide a textbox from main report's header in sub-report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I've a sales report of all customers for the company with each customer's sales summary page as the main report and individual transactions as a child report.

The main report has a heading/textbox in the header containing the word "Summary". The sub-report is in the last row of the tablix. Both the main report and the child report can span multiple pages. Additionally there are multiple sets of these main/sub-report (summary/transaction) combination, since it runs for all customers.

**1. How can I hide the "Summary" textbox from the parent report in child report's pages?**

What I've tried so far is that I've created a shared variable and using code behind I'm setting it to `True/False` (get/set functions). I set the variable to `False` before child report row in the main report and set it to `True` after the child report row. Then I've set the visibility of the TextBox using this variable. However, the problem I'm facing is that on the last page of the child report, the textbox appears again.